# dynamic flag or setting for case sensitivity behaviour in boost?

Tags: c++, regex, boost

With boost regex, is there a way to (dynamically) make ALL searches case insensitive (or not) with some flag or setting rather than having to make each regular expression case insensitive individually? I want to pass my program a flag for case sensitivity and then have all regular expressions (there are MANY!) be appropriate for that specification...

Comment: What's wrong with specifying boost::regex_constants::icase ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably maintain separate 
string's containing the regex,
and empty boost regex's.

Then when you start the program just
assign the string and flags to the boost regex.
Include myconst.h where you use the regex (and call SetupRegex()).

I.e.

***myconst.h***

```
 #include <boost/regex.hpp>
 #include <string> 

 using namespace std;
 using namespace boost;

 #define MYFLAGS   regex_constants::perl
 #define MYFLAGS_I regex_constants::perl | boost::regex_constants::icase 

 extern boost::regex rx1;
 extern boost::regex rx2;
 extern boost::regex rx3;

 void SetupRegex( bool bIgnoreCase = true );
```

***myconst.cpp***

```
 #include "myconst.h"

 string str_rx1 = " regex 1 ";
 string str_rx2 = " regex 2 ";
 string str_rx3 = " regex 3 ";

 boost::regex rx1;
 boost::regex rx2;
 boost::regex rx3;


 void SetupRegex( bool bIgnoreCase )
 {
     unsigned flags = MYFLAGS;
     if ( bIgnoreCase ) 
         flags = MYFLAGS_I;

     rx1.assign( str_rx1,  flags );
     rx2.assign( str_rx2,  flags );
     rx3.assign( str_rx3,  flags );
 }
```